# Marking an MPMediaItem (podcast) as listened to

Tags: iphone, objective-c, media-player, ios

Is there a way to update the 'listened to' status of an `MPMediaItem` from the iPod library?

I've tried using `MPMusicPlayerController` in `iPodMusicPlayer` mode and it does not mark the podcast as listened to once it finishes playing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see it's not possible to change media attributes from MPMusicPlayer controller.

The only thing you could try play back the podcast and jump to the last second, then play back the last second (and turn the volume to 0 for that second).

But this is no good way as well because, you have play back something this causes a stop of every other iPod playback.